# How I can create post like system using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```html
function get_posts2()
{

    global $conn;
    $user=$_SESSION['user_email'];
    $get_user="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$user'";
    $run_user=mysqli_query($conn,$get_user);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
    $user_id=$row['user_id'];
    $friendn=1;
   $friend_select="SELECT  * from friends where user_1_id='$user_id' AND friends_status='$friendn'";
    $run_select_friends=mysqli_query($conn,$friend_select);
    while ($row_friends=mysqli_fetch_array($run_select_friends)){
        $id_2=$row_friends['user_2_id'];

        $post_selcet="select * from posts WHERE user_id='$id_2'";
        $run_post_select=mysqli_query($conn,$post_selcet);

        while($row_posts=mysqli_fetch_array($run_post_select))
        {

            $post_id=$row_posts['post_id'];
            $u_id=$row_posts['user_id'];
            $post_title=$row_posts['post_title'];
            $content=$row_posts['post_content'];
            $post_date=$row_posts['post_date'];
            $post_image=$row_posts['post_image'];


            $user="select * from users where user_id='$u_id'";
            $run_user=mysqli_query($conn,$user);
            $row_user=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
            $user_name=$row_user['user_name'];
            $user_image=$row_user['user_image'];

            echo "
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-8'>
       
<div class='panel panel-default'>
  <div class='panel-heading' id='post_head'>
<div style='float: left'> <img src='user/user_image/$user_image' width='50' height='50'></div>
<div style='text-align: center'  id='post_title'> $post_title</div>

<div style='float: right'>
<div id='post_meta'>
 <a href='user_profile.php?u_id=$user_id' id='user_id'>$user_name</a>$post_date</div></div></div>
  <div class='panel-body'><p align='center'><img src=images/post_images/$post_image class='img-responsive'></p><p>$content</p>
  <p><a href='single.php?post_id=$post_id' style='float:right;'><span style='font-size: x-large' class='glyphicon glyphicon-comment'></span> </a>
  </p></div>
</div>       
       
       </div>
       </div></div>
       ";




        }








    }
    


}
```

I want to create a post like system as like as facebook or Instagram
any one can help me ?

My code is show that I get my post information then I use them to show in my page  but I now I want to create a system for like and dislike

Comment: show here what you tried so far ?

Comment: excuse me I cant understand your mean

Comment: show your code here what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first u must create "likeCount" or "dislikeCount" fields in u'r posts table then make ajax request for increase or decrease counts.

sample jQuery code.

```js
$(document).on('click','.vote',function(){
 
 var $this = $(this);
 var $postID = $this.data('post_id');
 var $action = $this.data('vote_type'); //example 'up' or 'down'
 
 $.ajax({

 url:'url/to/process/ajax',
 type:'POST',
 data:{
   action:$action,
   postID : $postID
  },
 dataType:'json',
 success:function(response){
  
  //do success action
  
  },
 error:function(){} 
});
 
 
});
```

Comment: mr kavian I am Iranian too thank you for your response can you show me the html code

Comment: <a href="#" data-post_id="10" data-vote_type="up">LIKE</a>
<a href="#" data-post_id="10" data-vote_type="down">DISLIKE</a>

Comment: mr kavian my ajax is very weak I am so sorry for that can you explain me ajax code thanks for very useful help